# Oracle 12c - select records that have sequences

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle12c

I have a table with the following columns:

```
employee_id number (PK);
unique_emp_id varchar2(20);
emp_uid varchar2(20);
```

I want to select all duplicate `emp_uid`'s where at least one `unique_emp_id` is `like '%-%'` and one `not like '%-%'`. How can I do this?

Example data:

```
emp_uid   unique_emp_id
--------- -------------
12345.12  12345.12
12345.12  12345.12-1
12345.12  12345.12-2
12345.34  12345.34-1
12345.34  12345.34-2
```

Result data:

```
emp_uid   unique_emp_id
--------  -------------
12345.12  12345.12
12345.12  12345.12-1
12345.12  12345.12-2
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `group by` and `having` solve this problem:

```
select emp_uid
from t
group by emp_uid
having sum(case when unique_emp_id like '%-%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when unique_emp_id not like '%-%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.emp_uid = t.emp_uid and t1.unique_emp_id like '%-%') and
      exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.emp_uid = t.emp_uid and t1.unique_emp_id not like '%-%');
```